Retrieve binary data from SQL Server to normal string in Laravel 10
i run laravel 10 with existing database using sql server
the table i use is :
USE [MDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[loginEx]    Script Date: 5/9/2024 01:18:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[loginEx](
    [id] [binary](13) NOT NULL,
    [password] [binary](13) NOT NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_loginEx] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


i try to find some id in sql server directly with this query :
SELECT [id] = convert(varchar, id)
      ,[password] = convert(varchar, id)
      ,[Email]
  FROM [MDB].[dbo].[loginEx] where id = convert(binary(13), '007kmy')

and give me result like this :
id = 007kmy
password = x77kmy
email = example@gmail.com

and then it try to get the that data using laravel 10 :
$user = loginEx::select('id', 'password', 'email')
            ->where('id', DB::raw("CONVERT(binary(13), '007kmy')"))
            ->first();

        if ($user) {
            $result = [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'password' => $user->password,
                'email' => $user->Email
            ];

            dd($result);
        } else {
            dd('User not found');
        }


and then the problem is come, the returned data is not expected like this :
array:3 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\test.php:42
  "id" => 7
  "password" => "x77kmy\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
  "email" => "example@gmail.com"
]

the id only show value id = '7' instead of '007kmy'
and password => "x77kmy\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" instead of "x77kmy"
the result i expected is :
array:3 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\test.php:42
  "id" => "007kmy"
  "password" => "x77kmy"
  "email" => "example@gmail.com"
]

any suggestion or help i appriciate, thanks

Those are likely the exact same strings, just rendered two different ways. The former just being a simple "print to screen" with non-printable characters not printed, and the latter being an escaped string that shows the non-printable null bytes.

The select should be something like: Table::selectRaw('convert(varchar, id) id, convert(varchar, password) password, email')->.....

@Sammitch thanks for your response. i think what you say is correct. but the problem is convert it to normal string as i wrote expected result and title .
so i can print it normally in blade {{ $user->id }}
@TUPKAP the selectRaw(...) you give is the same result

Side note: I am hoping that this is an introductory exercise for a programming class somewhere, and that once this exercise is completed, your instructor will tell you to "never ever ever store passwords like this again for the remainder or your professional career." The next lesson should be in the proper use of salted and hashed passwords, and the availability of many existing libraries that have already implemented authentication functionality the right way.
